# JavaScript part not functioning

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, web

So in a website I'm working with I tried to make searchbar appear when user click on search button.

seatch button - html :

```
<header class="header">
    <div class="icons"> 
                <div class="fa fa-search" id="search-btn"></div>
    </div>
</header>
```

search box - html :

```
 <form class="search-form">
            <input type="text" class="search" id="search-box" placeholder="Search here...">
            <label for="search-box" class="fa fa-search"></label>
 </form>
```

I added default css styles to make searchbox dissapear till search button clicks. (as adding it's right to a minus value)

```
.header .search-form {
    border: 0px solid;
    position: absolute;
    top: 110%;                      
    right: -110%;    /*<= this line here*/                   
    width: 50rem;
    height: 5rem;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: .5rem;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;            
}
```

and set out the "active class" to make event trigger (onclick get the searchbox to left from where is it)

note :- I checked this "right" value(in below) on search box and it was clearly on sight.

```
.header .search-form .active{
    right: 2rem;
}
```

and added the following script

```
let searchForm = document.querySelector('.search-form');

document.querySelector('#search-btn').onclick = () => {
    searchForm.classList.toggle('active');
}
```

but it doesn't seems to be working.

I tried it as adding function to js and set the element to

```
<div class="fa fa-search" id="search-btn" onclick="function_name()"></div>
```

it didn't work either, I double checked my path to JS file and <script src = ""> matches and it did. also tried to add the script as internal in html file right close and before to body closing tag. did not work either

```
<script>.......... </script>
</body>
```

I also tried to make the value right of active class, setting it as higher value, but nothing happened

Comment: There is no duplications in any of id,class names

Comment: I don't see any `header` class

Comment: my bad there is a header class in my original code, since I removed unwanted parts to paste code in here, I added header class seperately

Comment: Original code has header class,

Comment: What about if you change `.header .search-form` for `.search-form`, and `.header .search-form .active` for `.active`?

Comment: Your CSS assumes **.search-form** is a child of **header**. Is the correct?

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS selector `.header .search-form .active` gets the element that has the `active` class and is a descendant of the `.search-form` at the same time. The correct selector is `.header .search-form.active` (note the space between `.search-form` and `.active` that is not there anymore) points the element that has `search-form` and the `active` class at the same time.